# URI fragment with parameter prevents document readiness

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, dom

I'm new to JS.

I have such a script on the page with a function, that should, to my understanding be called when document is ready:

```
<script>

$(function () 
{
    myFunction();
});
</script>
```

If I access my webpage without URI fragment, `myFunction()` is called.
But when I add any URI fragment with parameter, it **is not** called

`{url}` - function called
`{url}#anything` - function called
`{url}#anything=1` - function **is not** called

Why does URI fragment with parameter in URL prevent document from being ready?

Comment: {url}#anything=1 is not valid. Try #anything1 or ?anything=1

Comment: @protob According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment
We can use fragments with parameters:
Like:  
http://example.com/data.csv#row=4  
http://example.com/foo.mp4#t=10,20  
etc.

Comment: Are you sure it is also valid for MIME "text/html"? I think it's for different formats

Comment: @protob Indeed, I cannot find where it is implicitly mentioned that it is valid for "text/html". However, I can't also find info that it is prohibited, and the main question is still the same - how can it influence document readiness

Comment: UPD:
I see an error message in the console `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #anything=1` coming from JQuery

Comment: I don't know how it influences jQuery, maybe try to encode "=" as "%3D" in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because website used an old version of jQuery (2.2.0)
After upgrading to version 3.6.3 issue disappears.
There is still error message in the console -
`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #anything=1`.

However, `$( document ).ready()` is called so the functions under

```
$(function () 
{
    myFunction();
});
```